# set of training images for a simple neural network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

do you know any good set of training images for my test neural network

preferably a **tagged** set of images of **numbers or letters**
or simple symbols

faces or real images might be too complex at this stage.
(i am tiring to implement a Boltzmann machine)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) has a bunch of different sets of training data, including handwritten digits, for example [Optical Recognition of Handwritten Digits Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Optical+Recognition+of+Handwritten+Digits)

Answer (score 6):

Another large repository of datasets, organized by application domain (classification, regression, segmentation, ...) is [MLcomp](http://mlcomp.org/datasets). It also allow you to compare the performance of your algorithm with many other standard methods.